# jquery validation and ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have problem with jquery validation and ajax form submit.

Here's validation code:

```
$(function() {
   $("#contact-form").validate({
       rules: {
               name: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 2,
                       maxlength: 32
               },
               email: {
                       required: true,
                       email: true
               },
               message: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 20
               }

       },           
       messages: {
               name: {
                       required: "Please, enter a name",
                       minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required"),
                       maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed")
               },
               email: {
                       required: "Please, enter an email",
                       email: $.format("Please, enter valid email")
               },
               message: {
                       required: "Please, enter a message",
                       minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required")
               }               
       },

       submitHandler:function(form) {
               form.submit();                         
        }
   }); 
});
```

Here's ajax code for submitting the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e) {

$('#name').val('Your Name');
$('#email').val('Your Email');
$('#message').val('Your Message');

$.ajax({
    url:'',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#success").show().fadeOut(10000);
        },
    error:function(data){
        $("#error").show().fadeOut(10000);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

What I try to do is form validation and then submit the form. After submit the form should appear again with initial values.

The problem is that when I remove ajax then validation works fine, but I need ajax code to re-display the form.

How I could make this two pieces of code work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your ajax call within the submitHandler function:

```
submitHandler:function(form) {
    //form.submit();     


    $.ajax({
        url:'', //you will need a url surely, perhaps $(form).attr('action');
        data:$(form).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#name').val('Your Name');
            $('#email').val('Your Email');
            $('#message').val('Your Message');
            $("#success").show().fadeOut(10000);
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(10000);
        }
    });                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works great. It looks like I tried to place to much in submit handler :) I put there the whole code related to ajax submit. It was enough to place there only ajax call as you've showed. Thanks again!